# how to change label on magento checkout page?

Tags: magento, checkout

i am very new to magento. i want to change label "State/Provision" from checkout page to "Area". please help by giving steps
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can change the label of billing and shipping address 
path info:-app/design/frontend/[THEME_PACKAGE]/[THEME]/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

You can edit this file then you will able change label